# Setting up web.config connectionString for SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, web-config

I am setting up my `web.config` file to use database created on my local SQL Server. I am not sure what to use as Data Source value, is it `PCMINJACL2` like the credential for server name in print screen?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's the db server name or "(local)" for a local server. See [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: is it case sensitive?

Comment: No, host names are never case sensitive.